# PostgreSQL. Узнать количество записей в каждой группе

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице есть записи с полем `price`. Нужно посчитать количество записей каждой группы. Группы формируются следующим образом:

Указывается число, например 5, и берется промежуток цен от 0 до 5. Каждая новая группа увеличивает промежуток на 5.

Из этих записей:

```
-------
price
23.00
22.00
14.00
13.00
7.00
24.00
3.00
4.00
```

Должен получиться вот такой результат:

```
-------
group count
1     2      // (цены от 0 до 5)
2     1      // (цены от 5 до 10)
3     2      // (цены от 10 до 15)
4     0      // (цены от 15 до 20)
5     3      // (цены от 20 до 25)
```

Условие для выборки группы получается вот такое - `price >= {min_price} AND price < {max_price}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select row_number() OVER(order by price_group) as rown, MIN(price) as min_price, MAX(price) as max_price, COUNT(*) as rec_cnt 
from (select price, trunc(price/5) as price_group from curprice ) as price_groups
group by price_group 
order by min_price;
```

curprice - ~114k записей.
время выполнения запроса ~100ms.

Вариант без подзапроса, спасибо Mike за подсказку:

```
select row_number() OVER(order by trunc(price/5)) as rown, MIN(price) as min_price, MAX(price) as max_price, COUNT(*) as rec_cnt 
from curprice
group by trunc(price/5) 
order by min_price;
```

Время выполнения кстати то же, то есть планировшику по бара(ба)ну как написать :-)

Comment: В этом варианте запроса группы с нулевым количеством пропускаются. Можно ли их вывести? Из полученного результата будет формироваться массив, где ключ - это номер группы, а значение - количество

Comment: и сколько ж их вам вывести? до 3 триллионов хватит? )

Comment: думаю что это не нужно - зачем выводить то чего нет и вероятно никогда не будет?

Comment: В моем случае их много не будет) Это упростит формирование массива. Не нужно будет делать проверку к какому промежутку относится данный результат

Comment: это зависит от того какую верхнюю планку взять если 3 триллиона то будет _много_ :-)

Comment: ну и я вам не формирователь запросов - возьмите NUTS да и придумайте :-)